# How to use a broadcast in a streambuilder? | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, broadcast, snapshot

I'm trying to grab data from firestore and show it inside a table in flutter. I firstly get the data inside a future function and then convert the future function to a Stream. When I use the Stream function inside the streambuilder the error "bad state: Stream has already been listened to". After a bit of research I found out, that a broadcast should solve the problem. But here is where it gets a bit tricky: For some reasons the broadcast does'nt get accepted and the page is loading endless. What am I doing wrong in my case?

Here is where the future function gets converted into a stream

```
Stream<List<dynamic>> LinkedOtherOffersAsStream() async* {
    List<dynamic> data = await getLinkedOtherOffers(); // asynchrone Future-Function
    yield data; // Send data to the stream
  }
```

This is in my OffersPage where the data should get printed out:

```
final StreamController<Stream<List<dynamic>>> controller = StreamController<Stream<List<dynamic>>>.broadcast();

  //This is where your "number" go in
  Sink<Stream<List<dynamic>>> get inputNumber => controller.sink;

  //This is where your "number" go out
  Stream<Stream<List<dynamic>>> get outputNumber => controller.stream;


  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inputNumber.add(OfferController().LinkedOtherOffersAsStream());

  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    controller.close();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

And here is my streambuilder:

```
 StreamBuilder <dynamic>(
              stream: outputNumber,
               builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return LinearProgressIndicator();
                   }
            return SizedBox(child:Column(children: [
             ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return  Card (
              child: ListTile(
                 title: Text(snapshot.data![index]["title"],style:  TextStyle(fontWeight: snapshot.data![index]["noticed"] == true ? FontWeight.normal : FontWeight.bold), ),
      subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data![index]["description"].toString()}...'),
      trailing: Text(snapshot.data![index]["createdAt"]),
        onTap: (){ShowDialog().OffersDialogOwnOffers(context, snapshot.data![index]["title"], snapshot.data![index]["description"], snapshot.data![index], snapshot.data![index]["createdAt"],snapshot.data![index]["offerId"]);
            },
             ),
               );
                 }
                   )
             ]),);
                 },
                  ),
```

Maybe it helps to understand stream problem better: I have two different Tabs and each tab holds one Streambuilder inside. When I switch between both tabs the above error (bad state: stream has been listened to) appears.

Thanks for the help :)

A different approach to solve the problem was this one but it did'nt help too:

```
final broadcaststream = OfferController().LinkedOtherOffersAsStream().asBroadcastStream(
    onCancel: (controller) {
      print('Stream paused');
      controller.cancel();
    },
    onListen: (controller) async {
      if (controller.isPaused) {
        print('Stream resumed');
        controller.resume();
      }
    },
  );
```